# Write a program, which converts the expression a b + c d e + * * into an expression tree using stack.

Tags: c++, tree, stack, binary-search-tree

**description**
I don't know how to do this task.... but i just created a tree  and enter value..can anyone please help me to do this task...the Stack is also of node type and we have to push value of operators like ab+ so we will push a as node then b as node and when + will come we make a tree and a and b will be its leafs node.

.Code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node()
    {
        data = 0;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

class Tree
{
    Node *root;
    void insert(int d, Node *node)
    {
        if (d < node->data)
        {
            if (node->left == NULL)
            {
                Node *leaf = new Node();
                leaf->data = d;
                node->left = leaf;
            }
            else
            {
                insert(d, node->left);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (node->right == NULL)
            {
                Node *leaf = new Node();
                leaf->data = d;
                node->right = leaf;
            }
            else
            {
                insert(d, node->right);
            }

        }
    }

    void inOrderDisplay(Node *subRoot)
    {

        if (subRoot != NULL)
        {
            inOrderDisplay(subRoot->left);
            cout << subRoot->data << "  ";
            inOrderDisplay(subRoot->right);
        }
    }

    void postOrderDisplay(Node *subRoot)
    {

        if (subRoot != NULL)
        {
            postOrderDisplay(subRoot->left);
            postOrderDisplay(subRoot->right);
            cout << subRoot->data << "  ";
        }
    }

    void preOrderDisplay(Node *subRoot)
    {

        if (subRoot != NULL)
        {
            cout << subRoot->data << "  ";
            preOrderDisplay(subRoot->left);
            preOrderDisplay(subRoot->right);

        }
    }

    void deleteSubtree(Node *subRoot)
    {
        if (subRoot != NULL)
        {
            deleteSubtree(subRoot->left);
            deleteSubtree(subRoot->right);
            cout << "\ndeleting: " << subRoot->data;
            delete subRoot;
            subRoot = NULL;
        }
    }

public:
    Tree()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
    ~Tree()
    {
        deleteAll();
    }

    void insert(int d)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            Node *leaf = new Node();
            leaf->data = d;
            root = leaf;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(d, root);
        }
    }

    void inOrderDisplay()
    {
        inOrderDisplay(root);

    }

    void postOrderDisplay()
    {
        postOrderDisplay(root);

    }

    void preOrderDisplay()
    {
        preOrderDisplay(root);

    }
    void deleteAll()
    {
        deleteSubtree(root);
    }

};
```

.Main Class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"task1.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    Tree tree;

    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.insert(14);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(11);
    tree.insert(18);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    //tree.deleteAll();
}
```

Comment: For the example you gave, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have here, you only have a `void insert(int d, Node *node)` function, no `void insert(operator o, Node *node)` function.

I think this shows that you missed an important point here. Every node in the tree can either be an integer (as you did) **or an operator**. In both cases, I'd call it a string. Every node that is not a leaf must be an operator, and all leafs must be integers (or strings that represents operators/integer in our case).

Then, iterating over your input, the first three item should result in something like:

```
    +
   / \
  a   b
```

The next step would be to build more sub trees (not sure of the definition of the input you have), keep them in your stack and then construct more inner nodes of the tree.

So if the tree I showed above is called `Tree(+)` (for ease of use), and the initial stack was `[a,b,+,c,d,e,*,*]`, then after one iteration you'll have `[Tree(+),c,d,e,*,*]` and you continue from there.